# UI5 List Binding not showing content

Tags: binding, sapui5

I have a list object which is bound to a UI5 List element. However the values are not showing. Please take a look at my code.

UI/xml Code:

```
<List id="statementList" headerText="Statements"
items="{ path: 'statementListModel>/' }">
    <StandardListItem title="{importance}" description="{importance}"/>
</List>
```

Binding in JS:

```
var result = JSON.parse(aData.responseData);
that.getView().byId("statementList").setModel(new JSONModel(), "statementListModel");
that.getView().byId("statementList").getModel("statementListModel").setData(result.statementList);
```

The list object is built like this:

```
result= {
    statementList = [
         {
              importance = "ASD",
              ...
         },
         {
             importance = "BDS",
             ...
         }       
    ]
}
```

However it is just not showing the content. The list has the correct size so the binding somewhat works but the content binding does not work:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the model name **EVERYWHERE**:

```xml
<StandardListItem title="{statementListModel>importance}" description="{statementListModel>importance}"/>
```